# group of order 80 is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we prove that group of order 80 is solvable without using Burnside's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem) ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $80=2^4\cdot5$, any group of this order has either a unique Sylow $5$-subgroup or a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup (why? Count elements), so either way it has a normal Sylow subgroup, and either it has a quotient of order $2^4$ , which is a $2$-group and this solvable, or a quotient of order $5$ which is abelian and trivially solvable, so the whole group will be solvable.

Comment: i have problem with counting elements. If number of sylow 5-subgroups is 6 then there is (5-1)x6=24 elements with order 5 will come and there should be total of 80. How is possible to other 80-24=56 elements come from sylow 2-subgroups?

Comment: @Johndresden See [here for counting](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-proof-showing-that-any-group-with-an-order-less-than-60-is-solvable). They have explained better than I can do.

Comment: @Johndresden The number of 5-Sylow subgroup is a number s.t. it's 1 modulo $5$ and also it divides $80$. So it's either 1 or 16. If it's sixteen then we have $4\cdot 16 = 64$ different elements of order $5$. This leaves us $16$ elements for the $2$-Sylow subgroup, which can create exactly one subgroup of order 16